# Let X be a non-negative continuous r.v. with pdf f(x)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let      $G(t)=\int_t^\infty$$f(x)dx$

Show that

$E[X^2] = 2\int_0^\infty$$tG(t)dt$

I have not taken a course in probability in years and remember a theorem where X has a density function $f$ and some Y=r(X) and then you use that to find the distribution function and subsequently density function of Y, but I can't recall you to find the expected value of $X^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the *Law of the Unconscious Statistician* (please see Wikipedia) we have
$$E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty t^2f(t)\,dt$$
Now use integration by parts, letting $u=t^2$ and $dv=f(t)\,dt$. Note that by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have $G'(t)=-f(t)$.

Comment: So I have $E[X^2] = G(t)t^2 + \int t^2f(t)dt$....I tried solving for G(t) from that but it does not match up with the original statement?

Comment: I also don't understand how this manipulation shows that the expected value of X^2 specifically is equal...unless I am missing a way of manipulating E[X^2] that would help clarify things

Comment: We need to find $\left. G(t) t^2\right|_0^\infty$. Our function $t^2G(t)$ vanishes at $0$. If $E(X^2)$ exists then $t^2G(t)$ vanishes at $\infty$. Note that by the *Law of the Unconscious Statistician* (please see Wikipedia) we have $E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty t^2f(t)$. That would really be a better place to start, integrate $t^2 f(t)$ using integration by parts, $u=t^2$ and $dv=f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: How do we know whether our function vanishes at infinity or not?

Comment: If you mean $t^2G(t)$, one can get it from the fact $G(t)$ is monotone decreasing, has limit $0$, and $\int_0^\infty t^2f(t)\,dt$ exists.

Comment: What about the fact that the give value for G(t) in the problem has integration bounds from t to infin? I understand the law of uncon stat and how we get to the $\int (2t)(G(t)$ portion, it's just the final punchline portion

Comment: That's what makes $G$ have limit $0$. But there remains the technical point of speed of convergence to $0$.